# SQL find rows with same value in one column, multiple in other and a set value in third column

Tags: sql

Apologies if the title isn't descriptive enough i'm not native.. 
So i have a following table NUMBERS

```
A..B..C..YEAR
1..1..1..2019
2..1..0..2019
2..2..1..2019
2..3..1..2019
2..4..1..2020
```

When column C is 1, every column A value should have only one value in column B in a single year. If there are multiple, it is an error that i need to find out about.

So i should make a query that gives me in this example rows 3 and 4. I tried as below, but that gives me also a row 5, because 'having count' seems to look through all the years, where as i only want to lookup with in a given year. How do i include the year for the distinct B's?

```
SELECT A, B
FROM NUMBERS
WHERE A IN (
   SELECT A
   FROM NUMBERS
   WHERE C = 1
   AND YEAR = 2019
   GROUP BY A
   HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT B) > 1
   )
;
```

Comment: I assume you mean one "b" value per "a" per "year".  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you want rows where there are multiple "b" values:

```
select n.*
from (select n.*,
             min(b) over (partition by a, year) as min_b,
             max(b) over (partition by a, year) as max_b
      from numbers n
      where n.c = 1 
     ) n
where min_b <> max_b
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add the year to the group by.

```
SELECT A, B
FROM NUMBERS
WHERE A IN (
   SELECT A
   FROM NUMBERS
   WHERE C = 1
   AND YEAR = 2019
   GROUP BY YEAR, A
   HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT B) > 1
   )
;
```